# How to implement a function containing imputation methods to aggregation primitives in featuretools?

Tags: dataset, primitive, imputation, feature-engineering, featuretools

I'd like to use mean/median/mode imputation methods for null values in a dataset.

The output is supposed to be a table with aggregated values already. I just have really no idea on how to do it..

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way would be to create your own custom aggregation primitive. You can read about that [here](https://featuretools.alteryx.com/en/stable/guides/advanced_custom_primitives.html).

I tried to distill your problem down to a very simple case of 2 tables. Check out the code below

```py
import featuretools as ft
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from featuretools.primitives import AggregationPrimitive
from woodwork.column_schema import ColumnSchema

class SumWithImputation(AggregationPrimitive):
    name = "sum_with_imputation"
    input_types = [ColumnSchema(semantic_tags={"numeric"})]
    return_type = ColumnSchema(semantic_tags={"numeric"})

    def get_function(self):
        def func(series):
            m = np.nanmean(series.values)
            series = series.fillna(value=m)
            return np.sum(series.values)

        return func

table1 = pd.DataFrame({
    "idx": ["a", "b", "c"],
    "desc": ["Orange", "Bananas", "Cake"],
})

table2 = pd.DataFrame({
    "idx": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    "cat_1": ["a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "c", "c"],
    "quantity": [10, np.nan, 10, 2, 2, 1, 1,]
})

dataframes = {
   "table1" : (table1, "idx"),
   "table2" : (table2, "idx"),
}

relationships = [("table1", "idx", "table2", "cat_1")]

fm, f = ft.dfs(
    dataframes=dataframes,
    relationships=relationships,
    target_dataframe_name="table1",
    agg_primitives=["mean", "sum", SumWithImputation]
)

fm
```

This will give you the following output:

[image: output]

The key part is here:

```py
def func(series):
    m = np.nanmean(series.values)
    series = series.fillna(value=m)
    return np.sum(series.values)
```

I'm filling in NaN values with the mean before performing the sum. You can replace this with any imputation strategy like a rolling window, etc.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for this! I have posted the code I wrote in another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71696066/how-to-transform-user-defined-function-into-a-custom-primitive